# WCF Parameter loses values

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure

I am populating a list of MyType with 20 elements, and passing it as a parameter to a WCF Service.

The only problem is that when it gets there, the list has no elements.

My service method is:

```
MyMethod(List<MyType> myList, string bla)
```

I'm calling it like this, from a Windows Forms App:

```
myService.MyMethod(myList.ToArray(), "bla"); // Here my list has 20 elements.
```

But when it gets to the WCF Service, the array is empty. :(

Could someone help me figure out why?

PS: My WCF Service is a Windows Azure Web Role, but I don't think it changes anything in this cenario. Or does it...?

Comment: What is the type of myList in your Winforms application? What type does ToArray() return?

Comment: myList is of the same type as the parameter, a defined type. In  this case, called "Registro". ToArray() returns an array of Registro, as "Registro[]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was in fact, a problem with namespaces and references...

Thank you guys.

Comment: I can only do that in two days, StackOverflow won't let me. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try a quick test application that self-hosts your service to verify that you're sending and receiving properly. If that works, then you can investigate Windows Azure as the cause of your problems.